# Catel: Using IMessageService in a AsynchronousCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

i binded a AsynchronousCommand to a Button of the View.
What i need to do is to validate some text boxes of the window when the user clicks on the button.
If the validation fails then an error message box should appear to the user.

How can i do this with the IMessageService?

Using this code:

```
            var messageService = GetService<IMessageService>();
            messageService.ShowError("Bitte wählen Sie einen Plan aus!");
```

i am getting the IvalidOperationException: invalidoperationexception the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

How can i avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to dispatch by using the IDispatcherService. It might be interesting to always dispatch in the MessageService.

If you are interested in such a feature, add a feature request [here](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer Geert, i will add a feature request as soon as possible when i am back in the office.